# How to send a very long xml file as payload in rest API Automation

Tags: rest, api, postman

I want to sent a very long xml as a payload in rest API Automation. 
    I am using the HTTP client framework.

```
restClient = new RestClient();
HashMap < String, String > headerMap = new HashMap < String, String > ();
headerMap.put("Content-Type", "application/xml");
headerMap.put("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "7531bf090b6b49199ec37f9c818dc417");

//jackson API:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Users users = new Users("morpheus", "leader"); //expected users obejct

//object to json file:
```

Comment: couple of questions - Long xml file is subjective? Could you please let us know how big is your file size? And second what is the exact problem you are facing right onow?

Answer (score 0):

You can create object of your XML and set the data using the getter functions() or create a xml file and put it into your project with some pupolated data which will always remain common. Read the external xml file and change it depending on your requirements before making request.

Answer (score 0):

Everything in body can be send as String, save long complex xml to in a file & then convert your XML file to string and pass to that json variable.

```
JsonRequest{
"name" : "${name}"
}
name= FileUtil.readFileToString(new File(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```